a· A· b = (ba)· ·A for given a and b (tensor algebra)
I am trying to solve this tensor algebra problem but I get an inequality.
Here is the problem:
The following vectors and scalars are given: a = i + 2j + 3k, b= j− k,
A is a dyad.
Show a· A· b = (ba)··A for given an and b.
The result I get in the left side is 28, and the right side 1.
I tried different methods of calculating the double product and I get the same result so it’s not a miscalculation.
Please help me understand what I’m doing wrong.
It would also be helpful if some can show the equality for any a, b, A.

What is your definition of $A{\cdot}{\cdot}B$ for two dyads? In the notation I know the inner product of dyads is denoted by $A:B$ and defined via $(ab):(cd) = (a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)$, in this case the identity would be $a\cdot A\cdot b = (ab):A$. But maybe you have different definitions.
